# Static Block Incorrect size

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, code

I am very much a novice when it comes to magento. I've self taught myself in areas i can. Long story short a web designer who was all the talk and not much of the walk designed a website for our store then left it all to us. I don't know code, but i was fiddling with some things and must of made an error with one of the static blocks and now our web pages is like this in the footer (see picture)

[image]

How can i change it to evenly spread across the page?

[image]

[image]

Here is info of the static block. Any help is appreciated,

THANKS!

Comment: just a tip for the future, post code as text, not screenshots

Comment: and if " I dont know code, but i was fiddling" then use a development site not a live one :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the info you have given but it looks like a css problem. On line 688 of this stylesheet https://www.chiverssports.co.uk/skin/frontend/athlete/default/css/local.css you need to remove the float and width.

change: `.footer .newsletter-container {float:right;  width:36.2549%;}`

to: `.footer .newsletter-container {/* float:right; width:36.2549%; */}`

the /* and */ comment out the code so it isn't seen by the browser

Comment: i think this is beyond me, i wouldn't know where to begin to change css . Thanks for the tips!